# Is it possible to run pdb and unittest python modules at the same time?

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging

For example:

`python3 -m unittest -m pdb test/test_string.py`
or
`python3 -m unittest pdb test/test_string.py`

So ideally I'd like python to start in debug mode on exceptions, but without add any extra code into the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Twisted and use Twisted Trial as you runner, you can do it like this:

```
trial --debug test/test_string.py
```

Tangentially, it's better if you put your tests in an importable package and name them by module name rather than filename (eg `test.test_string` instead of `test/test_string.py`).